# Installing oci cli on Windows 11 and it freezes

Tags: python, powershell, command-line-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to install oci cli on a new windows 11 build and am using this guide from oci website.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/cliinstall.htm#InstallingCLI__windows

The install freezes on this line `VERBOSE: Arguments to python script: "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC2B9.tmp"`

Full output below. Anyone know Windows 11 well and what might be causing this issue?

```
PS C:\Users\keega> iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oracle/oci-cli/master/scripts/install/install.ps1'))

******************************************************************************
You have started the OCI CLI Installer in interactive mode. If you do not wish
to run this in interactive mode, please include the -AcceptAllDefaults option.
If you have the script locally and would like to know more about
input options for this script, then you can run:
help .\install.ps1
If you would like to know more about input options for this script, refer to:
https://github.com/oracle/oci-cli/blob/master/scripts/install/README.rst
******************************************************************************
VERBOSE: Python found in registry: HKCU:\Software\Python\PythonCore
VERBOSE: Downloading install script to C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC2B9.tmp
VERBOSE:  False     False
VERBOSE: Using Python executable: C:\Users\keega\Python\python.exe to run install script...
VERBOSE: Arguments to python script: "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC2B9.tmp"
```

Comment: Read the error : VERBOSE: Using Python executable: C:\Users\keega\Python\python.exe to run install script...

Comment: I'm sorry but I have read that and it doesn't help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: It is not freezing.  The VEBOSE is telling you to run python with arguments  :  C:\Users\keega\Python\python.exe C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC2B9.tmp